# Attempt to index nested table and insert numeric character number

Tags: insert, lua-table

```
local file = assert(io.open("E:\\text.txt","r"))
local Table = {}
local function Sort()
for c in file:lines() do
    Table[#Table + 1] = {}
    print(c)
    for i = 1,#c do
        Table[#Table][i] = string.byte(c,i,i) 
        Table[#Table] = table.concat(Table[#Table])
    end
        print("hi")
        print(table.concat(table))
    end
end
Sort()
```

> -- error:8: attempt to index a string value(field '?')

This Lua code is supposed to traverse through the lines of the file and create a table with the numeric representation of all its characters.

Comment: Please specify language you're using in tags

Comment: I believe this to be lua. [Edit] tags if that is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your outer loop the first time through you set `Table[1] = {}`.  The first time through your inner loop you are setting `Table[1]` to the result of `table.concat` which is a string.  The next time through the inner loop when `i=2` you are attempting `Table[1][2]`, but `Table[1]` is now a string, hence the error.